# Python Dictionary Manipulation

Tags: python, strings, python-2.x, hash-map

I just finished working on a coding challenge for learning Python 2.7. Essentially, I'm a function that if it is fed a string such as:

```
"The man drank the drink and ate the bread and forgot the drink"
```

I get in return:

```
{'and': {'ate': 1, 'forgot': 1},
 'ate': {'the': 1},
 'bread': {'and': 1},
 'drank': {'the': 1},
 'drink': {'and': 1},
 'forgot': {'the': 1},
 'man': {'drank': 1},
 'the': {'bread': 1, 'drink': 2, 'man': 1}}
```

In other words, each word (that has a word following it) is a key, and the value is a dictionary of words that come right after, and the number of times that happens. (`drink` follows `the` twice in the string, hence the `2` value in its dictionary.

Here's the function I wrote to accomplish this end:

```
def word_counts(f):
      #Function to remove punctuation, change to lowercase, etc. from incoming string 
    def string_clean(file_content):
        fc_new = "".join([i.lower() for i in file_content if i not in string.punctuation])
        fc_new = fc_new.split()
        return fc_new

    f = string_clean(f)
    unique_f = f[:] 

    #For next part of function, get the unique words found in string. 
    #We'll then run each through the string and find words that follow
    #Pop() the last word, since nothing follows it 
    unique_f = list(set(unique_f.pop()))

    result = {}
    for word in unique_f:
        next_word_keeper = {}
        for _ in range(0, len(f)-1):
            if word == f[_]:
                if f[_+1] in next_word_keeper.keys():
                    next_word_keeper[f[_+1]] = next_word_keeper[f[_+1]] + 1 
                else:
                    next_word_keeper[f[_+1]] = 1
        result[word] = next_word_keeper
    return result
```

Feedback appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `string.punctuation == string.punctuation.lower()`.
2. You don't need `string_clean` to be a function as you only use it once.
3. Don't use `_` as a variable, and definitely don't in a loop, as most use it as a 'garbage' variable.
4. You can use `f[:-1]` to get the same as `u = f[:];u.pop()`
5. Your algorithm is ok, but can be a bit odd to read.

To improve your code I'd add `collections.defaultdict`.
This will allow you to remove the innermost if/else.
This is as if the value isn't in the dictionary it'll default it to something for you.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> next_word_keeper = defaultdict(int)
>>> next_word_keeper['test'] += 1
>>> next_word_keeper
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'test': 1})
>>> next_word_keeper['test'] += 1
>>> next_word_keeper
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'test': 2})
>>> next_word_keeper['test2'] += 1
>>> next_word_keeper
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'test': 2, 'test2': 1})
```

Using the above should get you:

```
def word_counts(f):
    f = f.lower().split()
    unique_f = list(set(f[:-1]))
    result = {}
    for word in unique_f:
        next_word_keeper = defaultdict(int)
        for i in range(len(f)-1):
            if word == f[i]:
                next_word_keeper[f[i + 1]] += 1
        result[word] = next_word_keeper
    return result
```

---

*But* this code is not the best when it comes to readability and performance!

Instead of going through the list multiple times, you can go though it *once*.
Using `enumerate` we get the current index, and then we can use it to get the next word.
And then using two `defaultdict`s we can simplify the function to six lines:

```
def word_counts(line):
    line = line.lower().split()
    results = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(int))
    for i, value in enumerate(line[:-1]):
        results[value][line[i + 1]] += 1
    return results
```

You can also go onto use the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#recipes) `pairwise` recipe to further simplify the code.